# Whirlwind tour of Eclipse?

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse, ide

Does anyone know of a whirlwind tour of Eclipse that would help a (former) Visual Studio user get up to speed with it?

I just want something that tells me where all the basic features are and what all the cool stuff I've heard so much about is?

So far I've been using it mostly as a text editor and have had some luck compiling and running programs in it. But... I'm a bit confused, for instance sometimes I can't seem to get out of debug mode.

I'me sure I'm just looking in the wrong places for everything as I'm used to a different interface.

Are there plugins for Eclipse that make it look and feel more like Visual Studio?

I'm using Europa at the moment because thats what the rest of my team use, howver I'm more than happy to migrate to Ganemede...

Comment: There was a question someone that was very similar to this about how to get used to Eclipse if you were a Visual Studio programmer. I can't find it though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Help -> Help Contents` (no joke) and read the `Workbench User Guide`:

Especially the Chapter `Concepts`.

The same chapter is also very well in the `Java Development User Guide`

I'm sure after reading these few pages, you'll already know more then the average Eclipse user (because needs `Help` this days?).

Comment: Thanks, Do i have to do something to install the help? All i get when I enter the basic tutorial is a line of text saying "This tutorial provides a step by step walk-through of the Workbench. " but there is no actual content.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/concepts/welcome.htm if you can't access the help directly from Eclipse.

Also IBM have an [Introduction to Eclipse for  Visual Studio users](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-eclipse-visualstudio/) (although I've never used visual studio so I can't gauge it's usefulness).